# How to Iterate over the list and convert the datatype

Tags: python, list

Below is my list

`list_a = ['20.3', '6.74', '323','a']`

Code is below

```
try:
    list_a = map(float, list_a)
except ValueError:
    pass
for i in list_a:
    print (i)
```

Expected result

`[20.3, 6.74, 323,'a']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following:

```
list_a = ['20.3', '6.74', '323','a']
for i,v in enumerate(list_a):
    try:
        x=float(v)
        list_a[i]=x
    except:
        pass
```

This would be working for your scenario.

Comment: Edited. Please check @aysh

Comment: what is list_a[i]=x is  doing? i didnt get

Comment: Just replacing the string value with the float value. **i** is basically the index.

Answer (score 1):

this cast data according to the datatype looks like

```
list_a = ['20.3', '6.74', '323', 'a']
result = []
for x in list_a:
    if x.isalpha():
        result.append(x)
    elif x.isdigit():
        result.append(int(x))
    else:
        result.append(float(x))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_a = ['20.3', '6.74', '323','a']
b=[float(i) if not i.isalpha() else i for i in list_a]
print(b)
```

This code works fine

Comment: The output will be `[20.3, 6.74, 323.0, 'a']`